# A modern-day scientist travels back in time to Nazi Germany

Tags: warfare, alternate-history, time-travel

What can he do with his knowledge of 21st century science and engineering to shift the tides of war in Germany's favor? Saying "help them build a nuke" isn't allowed (because it's way too obvious).

Comment: Open questions like this are not suitable for this venue.  You need to be much more specific (not broad) *and* have some criteria for knowing a correct answer.  So this will be closed as both *too broad* and *opinion based*.

Comment: A modern-day scientist can be someone who would not fit into Nazi society. Gender/racial stereotypes apply.

Answer (score 4):

#### Accidental or Intentional Travel?

If your story is about a weird event with an accidental victim, the question would be if the scientist *wants* to help the Nazis and if the Nazis want to accept help. A guy/gal without papers? Strange speech patterns with lots of English words and even grammar? The Nazis murdered Germans with disabilities because they didn't want to care for them, what will they do to an obvious madman who may not be German after all?

A bad guy in a story might want to time-travel intentionally. Somewhere between 5% and 20% of Germans have *some* right-wing, xenophobic political opinions, fewer aer outright Nazis. A non-German character would be another possibility, some sort of white supremacist. So what can the time-traveler bring?

Another question is when the time traveler will arrive. 1923? 1933? 1943?

- The time traveler will need something that works quickly to prove his bona fides and get the cooperation of the government. Memorize the location of some post-war Germanic archaeological finds which can be dug out by hand if necessary, that'll get him the ear of some bigwigs.
- Books with embarassing information on historical leaders. Who can be blackmailed?
- [Naked on arrival](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NakedOnArrival), only what he has in his mind. If he arrives early enough, memorize some engineering breakthroughs. Transistors? Radar? Air-independent propulsion for submarines?
- If he can bring a couple of suitcases, blueprints for the AK-47, the T-34, the Leopard I tank, the Mig-15, the B-29, the Type 205 submarine. A mix of things that can be done quickly and "stretch goals" for the future.
- Some books with *exact* locations of raw materials in Germany and beyond. Germany does not have much oil, but it helps if you know where to drill.
- A couple of books on modern management practice if the Nazis were prepared to put them into practice -- but they were a remarkably inefficient government controlled by personal relationships and special interests.

Comment: The raw materials idea is interesting. Just telling the Axis that there is oil in Italian Libya - with some time to develop it - could have changed the importance and outcome of the North African teatre.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the simplest answer is best. It doesn't require future science and engineering to turn the tide of the Second World War. The Germans only need to be told their [Enigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine) code was cracked by the Allies and they should add some extra rotors to their Enigma machines and improve their signalling procedures.

> Though Enigma had some cryptographic weaknesses, in practice it was German procedural flaws, operator mistakes, failure to systematically introduce changes in encipherment procedures, and Allied capture of key tables and hardware that, during the war, enabled Allied cryptologists to succeed and "turned the tide" in the Allies' favor.

This of itself wouldn't guarantee a German victory in the Second World War, but it would be an effective first step.

Next he could advise the German High Command that their V-weapons rocket program was essentially a waste of time, money and effort. Werner Von Braun had told Hitler in answer to the Fuhrer's question that rockets were the equivalent of artillery and he could make them in their thousands. Instead they should continue their development of jet aircraft.

Thirdly, the scientist should present the German High Command with a comprehensive set of military histories of the Second World war.

However, the OP omitted to suggest when this scientist arrived in Germany to begin the business of changing the course of history. The time of his arrival will radically determine the outcome of his activities.

It is recommended that the OP and anyone interested should take a look at the excellent Czechoslavian time travel comedy-drama [*Zítra vstanu a opařím se čajem*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVBPNfKfgNo)  or in English *Tomorrow I'll Get Up and Scald Myself With Tea* (1976). This involves taking suitcase hydrogen bombs back to the Nazis via a time machine. Yes the OP didn't want nuclear weapons, but you deserve the opportunity to enjoy one of the best time travel movies of all time.

Comment: I'd say this answers the question "A modern day *person* travels back...." nothing in this answer requires the protagonist to be a scientist

Comment: On the contrary this answer requires the protagonist to think like a scientist. Enigma coding has a mathematical basis of technical encryption. Jet aircraft as opposed to rocket weapons involving understanding of engineering and its military capability. More than simple science & engineering are needed, It requires knowing what will help turn the tide of war. Also, history can be considered a science as it depends on evidence and analysis. The question requires a scientist who knows about WW II. Yes a non-scientist could have the same knowledge, but so can a scientist.

Comment: Had the German nuclear weapon program been further developed, their advanced rocketry would have been very useful as a delivery system. So pushing the nuclear program and continuing or aiding the rocketry program is arguably better than abandoning both to focus on jets.

Comment: @Innovine The answer lies in economics. Germany spent the equivalent of the Manhattan Project on its rocket program. The cost of two Manhattan Projects would be out of their reach. Their jet aircraft program was successful in the early 1940s, but abandoned when they thought the war would be short. The OP has a no nukes requirement. Otherwise nuclear weapons would be the easy answer. V-weapons didn't change the War's outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Such a scientist could:

- Tell them that the "code" used my America was a native American language and by that help "break" the code
- Tell them when and where important battles were to expect (D-Day)
- Tell them who are key persons who lead to the allied victory
- Help them build their jet fighter aircraft earlier
- Help them to build better radar systems earlier to better defend against bombers from GB

One of the main reasons the allies won the war was that Hitler was insane and always wanted bigger weapons despite those being useless and lots of other mistakes he made. This is something a single scientist would not have been able to change. Examples of this are the [Mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panzer_VIII_Maus) and the fact that the first jet aircraft, the [ME226](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messerschmitt_Me_262) was used as a bomber not as an interceptor.